# Ports in Linux vs Windows

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I'm studying for a security class.
I know that ports in Linux are tied to a process. So if I wanted to close/shutdown a port, I'd end the process that's using it.

So if I'm in Windows, what's comparable?

I know there are firewalls for both systems (Windows firewall vs IPTables), but ports being tied to a process in Linux seems to be on a different level than a firewall.

Thank you in advance. When I tried Googling all I ended up with was links about configuring RDP and some Xbox stuff. I originally posted in Network Engineering, but they sent me over here.

Comment: The same really is true for Windows.  A process would use a port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ports are ports. A program creates a port as needed, and performs IO operations through it (same as reading/writing a file, except its through a port instead of a file path). The process is responsible for all operations on the port, including setup and teardown, regardless of the OS involved. This is all defined in the Transport layer protocols (TCP, UDP, etc) that all computers must implement in order to participate in IP networks like the Internet.

Ports are needed so that a packet can differentiate which service/process on the remote host they want to talk to. otherwise every IP address would be able to host exactly one service. with ports, you can run a webserver on 80, an email server on 25, and an dns server on 53. based on the port number, we know what service each packet is for.

look at the [Sockets programming interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_socket) for more info on how applications use ports for communication.

Firewalls have nothing to do with the ports themselves, other than that they can process packets differently depending on the port attribute they observe as the packet moves through them.

in order for a port to be "open", it must have a process listening on it, and an accessible path by which remote systems can access it. firewalls and NAT often block packets addressed to specific ports, but they do not affect whether the port is actually open.

Comment: Both are very good answers, thank you. This answer went a little more in depth on what I was looking for.